# uiscrollview autolayout refresh after move scroll

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

I have IBOutlet 2 property, scrollview and contentview, i create my view via xib, I Set all consraint inside contentview, now I need to put contentview inside scrollview, I try to do something like this:

```
[_scrollView addSubview:_scrollViewContent];
[_scrollView setContentSize:_scrollViewContent.frame.size];

_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_scrollViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollView, _scrollViewContent);
NSArray *scrollViewLabelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollViewContent(_scrollView)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[_scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabelConstraints];
```

initially not work, contentview is a bit larger then scrollview, when I scroll horizontally I see the view in the correct way.
Where is the error?